# PHP SMTP issue - unable to connect to ssl

Tags: php, smtp

I am using smtp mail setting and send mail successfully, but some time get below error, please help me what is error in code.

**----ERROR---**

> 283 and in the
>   file:home/xxx/public_html/xxx/class.smtp.php
>
> stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp-relay.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

```
Array
(
    [host] => ssl://smtp-relay.gmail.com
    [port] => 465
    [timeout] => 300
    [options] => Array (  )
    [streamok] => 1
    [errno] => 0
    [errstr] =>
    [socket_context] => Resource id #66
)
```

---

```
# SMTP Settings
$mail->Host = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->Username = 'noreply@xxxxxx.co.xx';
$mail->Password = '$$xxxxxxxx$$';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->SetFrom($GLOBALS["smtp_from_email"], $GLOBALS["smtp_from_name"]);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
# SMTP Settings
```

Comment: try $mail->Port = '587';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you use phpmailer ?

if you do

```
$mail->SMTPSecure ='tls'
```

and make sure that you telnet first to the smtp port that you use, to make sure that your network connection or the port that you going to use can be use